# Fill up emtpy array spots with prev value

Tags: php, arrays

I am using `PHP 7.3.5`.

I have an array with emtpy spots, which I would like to fill up values from the previous spot:

For example:

```
    0 => 'FriAug 1',
    1 => '',
    2 => '',
    3 => '',
    4 => '',
```

Should result in:

```
0 => '01.08.2019',
1 => '01.08.2019',
2 => '01.08.2019',
3 => '01.08.2019',
4 => '01.08.2019',
```

I tried the following:

```
<?php

$arr = array (
    0 => 'FriAug 1',
    1 => '',
    2 => '',
    3 => '',
    4 => '',
    5 => '',
    6 => '',
    7 => '',
    8 => '',
    9 => '',
    10 => '',
    11 => '',
    12 => '',
    13 => '',
    14 => '',
    15 => '',
    16 => '',
    17 => '',
    18 => '',
    19 => 'SatNov 2',
    20 => 'SunNov 3',
    21 => '',
    22 => '',
    23 => '',
    24 => '',
    25 => '',
    26 => 'MonJan 4',
    27 => '',
    28 => '',
    29 => '',
    30 => '',
    31 => '',
    32 => '',
    33 => '',
    34 => '',
    35 => '',
    36 => '',
    37 => '',
    38 => '',
    39 => '',
    40 => '',
    41 => '',
    42 => '',
    43 => '',
    44 => '',
    45 => 'TueDec 5',
    46 => '',
    47 => '',
    48 => '',
    49 => '',
    50 => '',
    51 => '',
    52 => '',
    53 => '',
    54 => '',
    55 => '',
    56 => '',
    57 => '',
    58 => '',
    59 => '',
    60 => '',
    61 => '',
    62 => 'WedNov 6'
);

$resArr = array();
foreach ($arr as $key => $v) {
    $prev = $key - 1;
    if($arr[$key] === '') {
        array_push($resArr, strtotime(preg_replace("^.{0,3}","", $arr[$prev])));
    } else {
        array_push($resArr, strtotime(preg_replace("^.{0,3}","", $arr[$key])));
    }
}

print_r($resArr);
```

My final result should look like the following:

```
// Wanted Result:
0 => '01.08.2019',
1 => '01.08.2019',
2 => '01.08.2019',
3 => '01.08.2019',
4 => '01.08.2019',
5 => '01.08.2019',
6 => '01.08.2019',
7 => '01.08.2019',
8 => '01.08.2019',
9 => '01.08.2019',
10 => '01.08.2019',
11 => '01.08.2019',
12 => '01.08.2019',
13 => '01.08.2019',
14 => '01.08.2019',
15 => '01.08.2019',
16 => '01.08.2019',
17 => '01.08.2019',
18 => '01.08.2019',
19 => '02.11.2019',
20 => '03.11.2019',
21 => '03.11.2019',
22 => '03.11.2019',
23 => '03.11.2019',
24 => '03.11.2019',
25 => '03.11.2019',
26 => '04.11.2019',
27 => '04.11.2019',
28 => '04.11.2019',
29 => '04.11.2019',
30 => '04.11.2019',
31 => '04.11.2019',
32 => '04.11.2019',
33 => '04.11.2019',
34 => '04.11.2019',
35 => '04.11.2019',
36 => '04.11.2019',
37 => '04.11.2019',
38 => '04.11.2019',
39 => '04.11.2019',
40 => '04.11.2019',
41 => '04.11.2019',
42 => '04.11.2019',
43 => '04.11.2019',
44 => '04.11.2019',
45 => '05.12.2019',
46 => '05.12.2019',
47 => '05.12.2019',
48 => '05.12.2019',
49 => '05.12.2019',
50 => '05.12.2019',
51 => '05.12.2019',
52 => '05.12.2019',
53 => '05.12.2019',
54 => '05.12.2019',
55 => '05.12.2019',
56 => '05.12.2019',
57 => '05.12.2019',
58 => '05.12.2019',
59 => '05.12.2019',
60 => '05.12.2019',
61 => '05.12.2019',
62 => '06.11.2019'
);
```

However, I only get `null/false` values in my final output.

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: You have no delimiters in your regex for starters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the problems is the use of the regex - your pattern isn't correct - but as it's just removing 3 chars of the front, it's easier to use `substr()` to remove them.

The second part is that you just look at the previous array position in the source array - which may also be blank.  This version just stores the last value generated (in `$prev`) and keeps on using it when needed...

```
$resArr = array();
$prev = "";
foreach ($arr as $key => $v) {
    if($arr[$key] === '') {
        array_push($resArr, $prev);
    } else {
        $prev = date("d.m.Y",strtotime(substr($arr[$key], 3)));
        array_push($resArr, $prev);
    }
}
```

This could be simplified without losing too much clarity to...

```
$resArr = array();
$prev = "";
foreach ($arr as $key => $v) {
    if($arr[$key] !== '') {
        $prev = date("d.m.Y",strtotime(substr($arr[$key], 3)));
    }
    array_push($resArr, $prev);
}
```

Comment: Nice answer. Couldn't you just simplify things with your if? For example `array_push($resArr, (!empty($arr[key]))? date("d.m.Y", strtotime(substr($arr[$key], 3))): $prev)`

Comment: @MojoAllmighty You could, I sometimes like simple code though (easier to read), but I have added an alternative version which makes it less bulky.